# Internet Explorer 7 collapses white space on an empty span, how do I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have the following markup:

```
<div><span class="first-name"></span> is really cool.</div>
```

which gets populated by AJAX/JavaScript after the page loads:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('/get-data', function (response.) {
        $('.first-name').text(response.name);
    });
});
```

In IE, this results in the white space after the span collapsing so I get: "Charlieis really cool." Doesn't happen in other browsers and I'm able to work around it for now by putting a `&nbsp` in the span for starters, but that feels like a big hack.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Also, here's a live example to run in IE 7 if you want: http://jsfiddle.net/rxAK4/.

Comment: Better to add a space after the inserted text. A non-breaking space may affect word wrapping, whereas an extra space (if there is one) will be removed by the browser to appear as only one space, so: `.text(response.name + ' ')`.

Answer (score 4):

I often find `&nbsp;` to be very handy when there's any question at all about whether or not a space I want will be displayed. I wouldn't have any problems using it here.